# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y' in Rstudio for ID3 algorithm

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, id3

[code_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBxS.png)
[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eichv.png)
I'm getting this error:

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

code:

```
library(RWeka)
WPM("refresh-cache") 
WPM("list-packages", "available")
WPM("install-package", "simpleEducationalLearningSchemes")
WPM("load-package", "simpleEducationalLearningSchemes")
ID3 <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/trees/Id3")
trial<-ID3(Intersection.~.,data = dataTrain)
trial
plot(trial) //error while running these line only
```

**Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'**
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtpSu.png)

***Actually, all that i want to do is just to plot a decision tree using ID3 algorithm, i know its the oldest algorithm but i have to make comparision table using ID3,C4.5,Random forest,CART and C5.0 and i am not even able to find proper code for ID3 in RStudio,so let me know if anyone knows the code for implementing ID3 algorithm in RStudio.***

Comment: but i did all these in Rstudio only. @user2554330

Comment: RStudio is a front-end for R.  Nothing in your question is RStudio-specific, it would be the same with any other front-end.

Comment: i have attached two images in the top line,you see i run these code in rstudio only. @user2554330

Comment: and if its all wrong ,then please let me know the right code for implementing ID3 algorithm in R/Rstudio. i need it for my research purposes and i am not even able to find it on google too excepting these lines of code which i have already used. Thanks :) @user2554330

Comment: well, i know its a front-end tool,and we cant use rstudio without R so i have already installed R first and then i am able to use this rstudio. @user2554330